# JPA @MapsId inserts 0 instead of correct value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have these entities (unnecessary columns removed for brevity)

**Order**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private Shipment shipment;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Shipment getShipment() {
        return shipment;
    }

    public void setShipment(Shipment shipment) {
        this.shipment = shipment;
        this.shipment.setOrder(this);
    }
}
```

**Shipment**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipments")
public class Shipment {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Order order;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "shipment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public ShippingAddress getShippingAddress() {
        return shippingAddress;
    }

    public void setShippingAddress(ShippingAddress shippingAddress) {
        this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
        this.shippingAddress.setShipment(this);
    }
}
```

**ShippingAddress**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipping_address")
public class ShippingAddress {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "shipment_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("shipment_id")
    private Shipment shipment;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Shipment getShipment() {
        return shipment;
    }

    public void setShipment(Shipment shipment) {
        this.shipment = shipment;
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I attempt to save a new `Order`. As you can see from the logs, Hibernate correctly sets the values to the `Order` and `Shipment` entities but assigns `0` to the `shipment_id` column in `shipping_address`, which of course causes a FK conflict.

I believe I'm using `@MapsId` correctly, because like I said, it works for the `Order` and `Shipment` relationship, but it doesn't seem to work for the `Shipment` and `ShippingAddress`.

These are the logs

```
2021-01-14 14:25:56,563 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL: insert into orders (branch_office, coupon_code, customer_id, external_id, increment_id, interests, origin_channel, store_id, subtotal, total, total_discount, total_qty_ordered) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-01-14 14:25:56,564 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,564 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,564 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [20]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,564 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [5501505642]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,564 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [5501505642]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,564 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [6] as [NUMERIC] - [0.0000]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,565 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [store]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,565 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - [55]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,565 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [9] as [NUMERIC] - [2270.0000]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,565 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [10] as [NUMERIC] - [1580]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,565 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [11] as [NUMERIC] - [690]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,565 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [12] as [INTEGER] - [3]

2021-01-14 14:25:56,621 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL: insert into shipments (carrier_id, pickup_id, shipment_id, shipping_cost, order_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-01-14 14:25:56,621 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [19]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,622 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [19]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,622 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,622 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [4] as [NUMERIC] - [0.0]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,622 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [20]

2021-01-14 14:25:56,623 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL: insert into shipping_address (city, country_code, province_id, street_name, street_number, zip_code, shipment_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Vicente López]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [AR]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [21]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [ramon melgar,Nro 8170]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - []
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [1638]
2021-01-14 14:25:56,624 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [0]
```

As you can see on the last insert, Hibernate attempts to insert a 0 instead of the `shipment_id`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You should never use primitive (non-nullable) types for `@Id`. Switch it to `Integer` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- From a correctness point of view, why shouldn't I use primitives for `@Id`?

Comment: Because the primitive is not capable of holding a value of `null` to clearly mean "unassigned", and it's possible for confusion to result if there is a real ID of 0.

Comment: You raise a good point. I'll update my entities to reflect that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) the value of the `@MapsId` annotation is referred to the name of the attribute within the composite key to which the relationship attribute corresponds. You do not use composite key.

So, this:

```java
@OneToOne
@MapsId("shipment_id")
private Shipment shipment;
```

should be corrected to this:

```java
@OneToOne
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id")
private Shipment shipment;
```

I can not find proof in the documentation, but hibernate ignore `@Column(name = "shipment_id")` on `@Id` when you use `@MapsId`, so you should specify PK column name of the `ShippingAddress` by adding `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that Hibernate generates the wrong column name. It generates `order_shipment_id` when it should be `shipment_id`. I fixed that by adding `@JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id")` under `@MapsId` in `ShippingAddress` and it works. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I can not find proof in the documentation. But I faced with it later. Hibernate ignore `@Column(name = "shipment_id")` on `@Id` when you use `@MapsId`.

Comment: You can use `@JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id")` as it referred to the PK of the target entity

Comment: That worked, even better! Should update your answer to reflect this. The final code should be:

`@OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "shipment_id")
    private Shipment shipment;`